Peut-on dire d'un objet, une voiture par exemple, « elle, elle est belle » ?
J'aurais plutôt dit « celle-ci est belle » mais je veux bien un avis.
Car l'usage du double pronom elle ou il pour un objet ne me semble pas correct.

La première occurrence est le pronom tonique complément, le deuxième est le pronom sujet.
